# Using the join method in python - confusing error

Tags: python-3.x

I have a very confusing problem.

This code prints out all combinations of length 3 and 4 for the word "caker"

```
from itertools import chain, permutations 

word = input("Please enter the letters or words to scramble: ")
perm_words = chain.from_iterable(permutations(word, i) for i in range(3,len(word)))

for item in perm_words:
    print(item)
```

In the following code (where I use the .join() method in the final for loop) I only get the 3-letter words. Why?

```
from itertools import chain, permutations 

word = input("Please enter the letters or words to scramble: ")
perm_words = chain.from_iterable(permutations(word, i) for i in range(3,len(word)))

for item in perm_words:
    word = "".join(item).lower()
    print(word)
```

The code is otherwise identical

Comment: Each item in perm words is its own tuple. ("a","c","k"),("k","a","c") etc... and the .join converts each item to a string (ack, kac etc...)

Comment: Don't modify word, assign the value to another variable and voila!

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because of lazy evaluation within `chain_iterator` and `permutations` because you are using the same variable name `word` in multiple places. Don't overwrite `word` and the issue is fixed.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations

your_word = 'caker'
perm_words = chain.from_iterable(permutations(your_word, i) for i in range(3, len(your_word)))

for item in perm_words:
    word = "".join(item).lower()
    print(item)
    print(word)
```

Output:

```
...
('r', 'k', 'e', 'c')
rkec
('r', 'k', 'e', 'a')
rkea
('r', 'e', 'c', 'a')
reca
('r', 'e', 'c', 'k')
reck
('r', 'e', 'a', 'c')
reac
('r', 'e', 'a', 'k')
reak
('r', 'e', 'k', 'c')
rekc
('r', 'e', 'k', 'a')
reka
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens but the issue is that you're assigning the value to word.

```
from itertools import chain, permutations 

word = input("Please enter the letters or words to scramble: ")
perm_words = chain.from_iterable(permutations(word, i) for i in range(3,len(word)))

for item in perm_words:
    other_word = "".join(item).lower()
    print(other_word)
```